# KeyError: 'email' when using pip install

Tags: python-2.7, pip, windows-7-x64, keyerror

I am getting a Keyerror whenever I try to install a new library using pip install (and other places too) ...

```
    ...
    from email import message_to_file
File "C\Python27\lib\distutils\email\__init__.py", line 115,
    setattr(sys.modules['email'], _name, importer)
KeyError: 'email'
```

Just to make sure I had all the correct files downloaded I went ahead and re-downloaded Python 2.7.5 - this did not fix the issue. Anyone know what is going on here? Running Windows 7 Home Premium.